# How can I make my component re-render when navigation param changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

To `Rank` component, following code will navigate to:

```js
navigation.navigate('Rank', { myData: someData });
```

In the `Rank` component, I'd like to re-render Rank when `someData`
is changed. But **getDerivedStateFromProps** in the Rank component does
not called when someData changed. I've checked that someData is changed.

Comment: Please share the full code of Rank component
Are you using ReactHook?

Comment: **someData** should be a state so you can put *navigate command* in **useEffect** or **componentDidMount**. it will automatically re-render Rank Component when it changed.